# How to show that in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$, $(X + 1)^{p^n}=X^{p^n}+1$?

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Suppose $p$ is prime, show that $(X + 1)^{p^n}=X^{p^n}+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. I found this question in a past term exam, and my teacher had it even generalised in the lesson with $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{F}_p[X], (a+b)^{p^n}=a^{p^n} + b^{p^n} $ but without giving any proof of this. Only indication is to use recurrence on $n$.

I didn't manage to prove it, but here's my attempt:

$n = 0$ we have $(X + 1)^{p^n}=(X+1)^1=X^1 + 1= X+1$, so true.

Now suppose this is true for $n$, and let's show that it still hold for $n+1$. So we have $(X + 1)^{p^n} = X^{p^n} + 1$, thus $(X + 1)^{p^{n+1}}=(X + 1)^{p^n}(X+1)^p= (X^{p^n} + 1)(X^p + 1)=X^{p^{n+1}}+ X^{p^n} + X^p + 1$

And I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a commutative ring, we can use binomial theorem: $$(X+1)^{p^{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^{p^{n}}\binom{p^{n}}{k}X^k.$$ Now show for $k\in \lbrace 1,\ldots p^{n}-1\rbrace$ that $p$ divides $\binom{p^{n}}{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $(X + 1)^{p^{n+1}}=(X + 1)^{p^n}(X+1)^p$ is wrong, since the RHS is $(X + 1)^{p^{n} + p}$ !

You should notice that
$$(X + 1)^{p^{n+1}}=\left(  (X + 1)^{p^n}  \right)^p$$
and use your induction hypothesis (as well as the case $n=1$).

The key idea is that the map $A \to A, a \mapsto a^p$ is a ring morphism, whenever $A$ is a ring whose characteristic is a prime number $p$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right, my bad! And now I immediately see how to solve it! Thank you!